# How to run Nginx + SSL in docker?

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl

This configuration was tested without docker. The site on SSL was launched without errors. Now when I want to run this server configuration in docker, I get no errors during installation, but the server does not start at all.

**nginx.dockerfile**

```
    FROM nginx:stable-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html
WORKDIR /var/www/html
RUN addgroup -g 1000 laravel && adduser -G laravel -g laravel -s /bin/sh -D laravel

RUN chown laravel:laravel /var/www/html

COPY ./nginx/ssl/mysite.ru/mysite_ru.crt /etc/nginx/ssl/mysite.ru/mysite_ru.crt
COPY ./nginx/ssl/mysite.ru/mysite_ru.key /etc/nginx/ssl/mysite.ru/mysite_ru.key

RUN apk update \
&& ln -sf ./nginx/ssl/mysite.ru /etc/nginx/ssl/mysite.ru

ADD ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
ADD ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

the `./nginx/ssl/mysite_com` folder contains working files: `mysite_com. crt` and `mysite_com.key`
This files checked without docker

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  site:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: nginx.dockerfile
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
      - ./nginx/ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
      - postgres
    networks:
      - laravel
```

**default.conf**

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name  mysite.ru;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mysite.ru/mysite_ru.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mysite.ru/mysite_ru.key;
    index index.php index.html;
    root /var/www/html/public;

        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Tell me, what is the error?
and where can I view nginx logs in docker?

Comment: You're not mounting the certificates in the `docker-compose` spec's `volumes` mappings for the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have not added or copied your SSL cert and key files to your nginx image.

Add `COPY` keyword before `RUN apk update ...` and then restart `nginx` at the end so that your `Dockerfile` looks like this and I think it should solves your problem:

```
FROM nginx:stable-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html
WORKDIR /var/www/html
RUN addgroup -g 1000 laravel && adduser -G laravel -g laravel -s /bin/sh -D laravel

RUN chown laravel:laravel /var/www/html

COPY mysite_com.crt /etc/nginx/ssl/mysite.com/
COPY mysite_com.key /etc/nginx/ssl/mysite.com/

RUN apk update \
&& ln -sf ./nginx/ssl/mysite_com /etc/nginx/ssl

ADD ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
ADD ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Comment: I've edited my answer, I think you just need to `copy` the key and cert files into the container. Check it again.